# How does bash handle pattern matching of '*'

Tags: bash, glob

My question is that how does bash expand '*' ?
like for this example with the echo command :

```
echo m*i*n*
```

I understand that any file or directory that has a letter m at the start, with a letter i at the m, and end by a letter 'n' will be valid expands.
However the below example does not expand to any files that matches this pattern am I missing something.

```
echo m*i*n
```

What are the rules for expands with '*' in bash ?

Comment: Do you have any files that end with `n`?

Comment: `*` is not an operator that affects the previous character; it represents 0 or more arbitrary characters by itself.

Comment: Nop i Don't but why the first echo expand to those files while the second do not work ? what are the rules set for expands with '*' in bash ? I have to reproduce that behavior in my C program. the files that I have is 'minishell.c' and 'minishell_utils.c'

Comment: `*` matches any strings, including null string. So both `m*i*n` and `m*i*n*` should match `m1i2n`.

Comment: Why did you replace '*' by numbers and what would mean this expression in litteral english ?

Comment: If you want an english word, they both match `meditation`.

Comment: I wasnt meaning this english litterate, rather how dors bash read the following line to produce it’s output ? 
How is 'echo m\*i\*n is read by bash ?

Comment: The basic syntax is documented at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html -- bash has some optional, off-by-default extensions, but you'd want to read bash's own documentation for them. Asking people to duplicate things that are already in the documentation is not a good use for our site -- the docs are more canonical, so they're the right place to go.

Comment: For a reference that covers bash's extensions to the basic fnmatch specification, see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern

Comment: That said, your software written in C can just use the `fnmatch` function directly; no reason to reinvent any wheels. If you'd asked "How can I implement shell-style globbing in C?", you would have gotten the answer you were looking for much more directly.

Comment: (Whereas "what's the _most efficient_ way to implement fnmatch-style patterns?" is a different question, and likely to involve the same NFA techniques used for high-performance regex matching; see https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html for some backstory)

Comment: See [comp.lang.c FAQ list - Question 13.7 (I need some code to do regular expression and wildcard matching.)](https://c-faq.com/lib/regex.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` matches zero or more characters.
The patterns are different, sou you may get different results. The `m*i*n*` allows characters after the `n`, the `m*i*n` requires `n` to be the last character in the filename.

As examples, see the table below:

```
               |     Matches:    |    
Filename       | m*i*n* | m*i*n  |
---------------+--------+--------+
 meditation    | yes    | yes    |
---------------+--------+--------+
 mipan.jpg     | yes    | no     |
---------------+--------+--------+
 mai.png       | yes    | no     |
---------------+--------+--------+
 mai.bin       | yes    | yes    |
---------------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

#### BASH provides **Globbing** feature.

In the Bash CLI when manipulating with file names, you may use this feature using glob characters in your **pattern** so that Bash will match all the existing file names based on the provided pattern.

The `*` is one of the glob characters that will basically match with any character (one or more) in the file name except the **dot `.`** character at the very beginning of the file name.

##### How it works in brief

Bash observing a glob character will actually first match all files in your current directory (if a path is not provided in the pattern), and then runs the command (`echo` in this case), providing matched file names to it and runs the process.

##### Example pattern and possible matches

Assuming the following files are available in your current working directory:

`file1.txt  file2.txt  1.gpeg  2.gpeg  temp  dir1  .file1  .dir2`

1- If you run such command/pattern:

`echo *`

- So you will get the following output:

  - `file1.txt  file2.txt  1.gpeg  2.gpeg  temp  dir1`

2- If you run the following command/pattern:

`echo *.gpeg`

- You will get the follwoing output:

  - `1.gpeg  2.gpeg`

To get more familiar with Globbing, glob characters, and the way Bash threats them I'd suggest have a research.

PS. You may find [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-globbing) usefull.

Comment: It's globbing not globing. Sigh.

Comment: Note that questions that are too broad to be answered _completely_ should not be answered at all. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). And please don't use syntax highlighting for things (like technical terms) that aren't actually syntax; `echo` is syntax, "glob" is not.

Comment: (Moreover, if you read the comments on the question, the OP doesn't want to know _what it does_ as much as they want to know _how to implement it themselves_ in their own shell they're building for school)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, my approach is to answer with providing the basic knowledge necessary to the topic so the OP may find it useful and gain the knowledge hopefully, instead of using it as a cheat-sheet. Hope this is not against the rules?

Comment: @Vab Thanks for your answer it was what I needed to fully complete this projects !